# Getting the number of leads in a list

Tags: marketo

I'm attempting to export leads from a Marketo list into my system, but I'd like to be able to display a progress bar with the total number of leads in the Marketo list. Is there a way to find the total number of leads in a given list using the Marketo Rest API?

Answer (score 0):

The Get Import Lead Status(http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-import-lead-status/) call will return numOfLeadsProcessed which you can compare to the number of rows in your list, to give an approximation of total progress.  You shouldn't need the existing size of the destination list to know the progress which you've made.

Comment: I'm actually trying to import the leads into my system, not into Marketo. I guess my original question wasn't quite clear on that, I went ahead and updated it.